# Android including layout file (reference id)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to include an existing layout in another layout file (xml). To position those layouts I need to give the included layout an id, so i am able to reference it, e.g.

I am using the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am including this layout in another layout, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    >
    <include android:id="@id/bar" layout="@layout/bar"/>  

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bar"
        >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
       ...
      </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This works fine and my ScrollView gets positioned below my bar and I am able to click on the bar, without the click events being intercepted by the ScrollView.

When I am trying to do the same in a different layout file it says that it can´t find the resource @id/bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutContainer2"
    >

    <include android:id="@id/bar" layout="@layout/bar"/>

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollview2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/bar"
        >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">
        ...
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Anybody knows why that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `android:id="@id/bar"` to `android:id="@+id/someId"`

Comment: thx, that was the only thing i didn't try, cause i wanted to use an existing id, but @+id fixed it so far. I am still curious though why it did work for one case, but not the others.